# Align dashes in the corner of a CAShapeLayer with a dashed border

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

I’ve got a CAShapeLayer with rounded corners and a dashed border that display line dashes. However, the dashes are not aligned to the corners. Is there a way to do this?

Here’s a diagram showing the kind of pattern I want (with the arrow pointing to it):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the 'phase' via https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/setLineDash:count:phase:

Comment: Specifically, set the phase to half of the dash length. This works as long as the width and height are multiples of twice the dash length.